# Import CSV data into an existing table using a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to update specific columns from a csv in an existing column from a table using a Stored Procedure?

I have an existing table: `dbo.customeremp`

It has current values:

| emp_id | Full_Name | Job_Title | Promoted | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159753 | Josh Smith | Engineer |  |  |
| 159745 | Ashley James | Admin |  |  |
| 158488 | Tui Vatu | IT |  |  |

We have a csv file which has the same column names above but has the Promoted values filled. Values: Yes , No

CSV file is located in \\Customer\customeremp.csv

My aim is that if said SP is executed, it picks up the csv file and updates the table mainly the Promoted column and want it so that Timestamp is also filled which returns the date and time of when this the SP is executed:

| emp_id | Full_Name | Job_Title | Promoted | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159753 | Josh Smith | Engineer | No | 2022-09-06 17:50:00 |
| 159745 | Ashley James | Admin | Yes | 2022-09-06 17:50:00 |
| 158488 | Tui Vatu | IT | No | 2022-09-06 17:50:00 |

Comment: What does the actual file look like? If it's a CSV compatible with RFC 4180 you can use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#format--csv) with the `FORMAT = 'CSV'` option. If not, you'll have to specify the correct field and line separators

Answer (score 0):

You can use BULK INSERT to copy data from the file into a temporary table that will be a staging one with all columns in NVARCHAR and then do a query from the temporay table to UPDATE the final table

[On BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[On UPDATE with joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object)